# issue with array allocation using sizeof in C

Tags: c, arrays, allocation, corruption

```
mid= n / 2;//(where n is 10)

int left[sizeof(mid)];
```

but compiler allocate space for 4[0,1,2,3] elements, it suppose to allocate for 5[0,1,2,3,4] elements.

what could be the issue?

Comment: Hum, what's your problem?

Comment: I'm *almost* interested in seeing the quicksort or mergesort algorithm being coded, just to see if it is done properly. Almost...

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` mean: the size in memory. int is 4 bytes in memory. so sizeof(int)=4.

You probably want to write `int left[mid];`